# Check Box Select Event

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have 3 Checkbox in my MVC Application, that I created like this,

```
@Html.CheckBox("chkAllExpenses", Model.NewVCARequest != null ? Model.NewVCARequest.allexpenses == 1 : true, new { @class = "chkMealPlan" })

@Html.CheckBox("chkTransportation", Model.NewVCARequest != null ? Model.NewVCARequest.Transportation == 1 : true, new { @class = "chkMealPlan" })

@Html.CheckBox("chkAllExpensesExcept", Model.NewVCARequest != null ? Model.NewVCARequest.Allexpnsesexc == 1 : true, new { @class = "chkMealPlan" })
```

I have applied Chosen style to the check boxes. Now i want to handle the change event of a check box. I want to disable the Last two when the first one is selected..

Comment: Is this ASP.NET? You never wrote which language this is. Also, if only ONE is allowed to be selected, use a radio button instead.

Comment: Yes, Its in Asp. Net MVC 4.  I want to disable the last two when the first one is clicked. Also when the second one is selected i want to disable the first one. The flow is like this.

Comment: So it goes like this: You select the first and the two last are disabled. Then you can't click the second one, because it is disabled, but if you manage to click it anyway, it should disable the first one? You need to pick your words wisely. I still don't see how this has anything to do with jQuery.

Comment: If the user select the first one, the last two will be disabled. When the user un check the first one, the last two will be enabled. This is the flow i want to implement.

Comment: Your use of `CheckBox()` makes no sense. Its for binding to a `boolean` property and generates 2 inputs with vales `true` and `false`. If you disable it, it will always post back `false` (in which case you un-check the other checkboxes, not disable them). But I suspect your model does not even contain `bool` properties for `chkAllExpenses`, `chkTransportation` etc. You appear to have the classic [X Y Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) and what you really want to do is use radio buttons to select one of 3 values

Answer (score 0):

Hope this will help.

```
$('.chkMealPlan').click(function(){

$('.chkMealPlan').not(':checked').prop('disabled',true);

});
```